# Did Duryodhana ever insult Draupadi by his words?

Tags: mahabharata, karna, draupadi, duryodhana

Karna insulted Draupadi by his words several times. One of the intensive insults happen during Draupadi vastrapaharanam.

> I will give. O son of the Kuru race, the gods have ordained only one
> husband for one woman. This Draupadi, however, hath many husbands.
> Therefore, certain it is that she is an unchaste woman. To bring her,
> therefore, into this assembly attired though she be in one piece of
> cloth--even to uncover her is not at all an act that may cause
> surprise. Whatever wealth the Pandavas had--she herself and these
> Pandavas themselves,--have all been justly won by the son of Suvala. O
> Dussasana, this Vikarna speaking words of (apparent) wisdom is but a
> boy. Take off the robes of the Pandavas as also the attire of
> Draupadi.
>
> [[Section 67, Sisupala-badha Parva, Sabha Parva, The Mahabharata]](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m02/m02067.htm)

Are there any statements by Duryodhana that insult Draupadi? I am not asking for insulting gestures. I am only asking for insult by words.